# Java Stream sortingBy and filter()

Tags: java, dictionary, filter, java-stream, groupingby

I have a specific question about Java 8 streams. I could not find anything that was close to the solution of my problem even it sounds not too complicated.

I want to convert a `List<Person>` into a `Map<Company, List<Person>>`. The Company is an enum. Now the `Map` should be grouped by the `Company` (so far I got everything working. After I want to filter all the `List<Person>` of the `Map` by an attribute : the Name of the `Person`. I only want to have the Person(s) with the longest name inside. Example:

This is what I got so far:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PersonMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person("Pete", Company.APPLE);
        Person person2 = new Person("Joe", Company.APPLE);
        Person person3 = new Person("Jack", Company.APPLE);
        Person person4 = new Person("Robert", Company.MICROSOFT);
        Person person5 = new Person("Cate", Company.MICROSOFT);
        Person person6 = new Person("Abi", Company.MICROSOFT);

        List<Person> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(person1);
        list.add(person2);
        list.add(person3);
        list.add(person4);
        list.add(person5);
        list.add(person6);
    }

    public Map<Company, List<Person>> groupPersonByCompanyAndFilterByName (List <Person> list){
        Map<Company, List<Person>> outputMap =
                list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCompany))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getValue().stream().toString().length() !=
                p.getValue().stream().map(Person::getName).mapToInt(String::length).max().getAsInt())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

        return outputMap;
    }
}
```

The filter function is not working here. The output I want is:

```
{MICROSOFT=["person4"], APPLE=[person1, person3]}
```

Does anybody have good knowledge and can help me please!

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to do this with just streams. You can either go through each individual sublist afterwards, find and remember the length of the longest name and then filter out everything in a second pass that does not have have that length. Or you go through the sublist once and add all names to another list if they are equal to the longest you've encountered so far. If you encounter a name that is longer than the longest you've found so far, you clear the current list before adding the name to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better performance, you shouldn't do it in a single stream chain.

Try this instead:

```
List<Person> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(new Person("Pete", Company.APPLE));
list.add(new Person("Joe", Company.APPLE));
list.add(new Person("Jack", Company.APPLE));
list.add(new Person("Robert", Company.MICROSOFT));
list.add(new Person("Cate", Company.MICROSOFT));
list.add(new Person("Abi", Company.MICROSOFT));

Map<Company, List<Person>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCompany));
map.values().forEach(persons -> {
    int maxLen = persons.stream().mapToInt(p -> p.getName().length()).max().getAsInt();
    persons.removeIf(p -> p.getName().length() != maxLen);
});

System.out.println(map);
```

*Output*

```
{APPLE=[Pete, Jack], MICROSOFT=[Robert]}
```

For the above code, I used the following extra classes:

```
enum Company {
    APPLE, MICROSOFT
}

class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final Company company;
    public Person(String name, Company company) {
        this.name = name;
        this.company = company;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public Company getCompany() {
        return this.company;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using teeing

```java
public Map<Company, List<Person>> groupPersonByCompanyAndFilterByName (List <Person> list){
    return list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Person::getCompany,
           teeing(
                  mapping(Person::getName, maxBy(Comparator.comparing(String::length))),
                  toList(),
                  (a, b) -> b.stream().filter(x -> x.getName().length() == a.get().length())
                                      .collect(toList())

           )
    ));

}
```

Comment: Nice!  But it does require Java 12+

Answer (score 0):

You can do it grouping by on multiple fields `Company` and length of `name`

```
Map<Company, Map<Integer, List<Person>>> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCompany, Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getName().length())));
```

And the create `Entries` from outer map `key` and inner map `value` having max length (name) which is inner map `key`

```
Map<Company, List<Person>> resultMap = map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(),
                    e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                            .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Person>>::getKey)).get().getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

You can combine these two operations into single stream also

Answer (score -2):

```
     Person person1 = new Person("Pete", "APPLE");
            Person person2 = new Person("Joe", "APPLE");
            Person person3 = new Person("Jack", "APPLE");
            Person person4 = new Person("Robert", "MICROSOFT");
            Person person5 = new Person("Cate", "MICROSOFT");
            Person person6 = new Person("Abi", "MICROSOFT");

            List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();

            list.add(person1);
            list.add(person2);
            list.add(person3);
            list.add(person4);
            list.add(person5);
            list.add(person6);

  //Adapt your structure and with this function you can group  
            Map<String, List<Person>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.getCompany()));

            for (String name: map.keySet()){
                List<Person> persons = map.get(name);
                System.out.println("[" + name + "]");
                persons.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getName()));
            }
```

Out Log:
[APPLE]
Pete
Joe
Jack
[MICROSOFT]
Robert
Cate
Abi

Comment: I just wrote you how to group better.
On the other hand I don't understand what you want to achieve

Comment: The OP wants to group by Persons with the longest name per company.  If there is a tie for longest name, include all of them for that length.